Intel hardware acceleration all filters work except transpose
I have been using vpp_qsv for hardware accelerated filtering for a couple of years.  I have used deinterlate, denoise, detail, framerate, saturation, contrast, brightness, cs, ch, cx, cy, w, and h and they all work as expected.  But now I want to do a horizontal flip: transpose=hflip, and it fails.  I get
[Parsed_vpp_qsv_0 @ 000001666e1ab240] Sync failed
using ffmpeg 4.4, and
[Parsed_vpp_qsv_0 @ 0000025c44c36900] Error running VPP: unsupported (-3) [vf#0:0 @ 0000025c44b86440] Error while filtering: Function not implemented [vf#0:0 @ 0000025c44b86440] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented) [vf#0:0 @ 0000025c44b86440] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented) [vost#0:0/libx265 @ 0000025c44b9e580] Could not open encoder before EOF [vost#0:0/libx265 @ 0000025c44b9e580] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument) [vost#0:0/libx265 @ 0000025c44b9e580] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument) [out#0/mp4 @ 0000025c44b8e440] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no pack
using ffmpeg 7.0, both on Windows 10 with the latest Intel driver from the Intel website.  Does anyone have any insight on why this filter doesn't work, and how to fix it?
